# How to play videos in vitamio player from vimeo and facebook?

Tags: android, video, vimeo, vitamio

I use vitamio player in my android app. But it cant play videos from facebook or vimeo with links (for example) : 
https://player.vimeo.com/video/91775232
or
 http://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F151536738227392%2Fvideos%2F173954162652254%2F&show_text=0&width=400

It always says, that "Sorry, this video cannt be played".

Help me please, i really need to play this videos by links in app. I tried to use webview, but it was bad idea - webview cant play that videos in all android deviced and all android versions. So, is there a way to play this videos in vitamio player?

Answer (score 0):

You can try webview with setWebChromeClient or try chrome custom tabs then your videos should play.

Comment: Unfortunately, webview cant play videos on all deviced and os versions without bugs. For example, on samsung galaxy duos (os 4.1.2) webview shows videos without full-screen button or doesnt show video (only sound with black screen).